# Create multiple menu items

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have two scripts I'm making:

1. Shorten URLs within a Google Sheet
2. Printing a single sheet and sending this as a PDF to a specified email

I have successfully created the first script and added it as a menu item in my Google Sheet, but notice that when I started working on the second script, the first menu item has disappeared!

Is there a way to have both scripts show as menu items please?

Comment: See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82669/88163) to  [Google Sheets Customize View Using Create Custom Menu and Hiding/Showing Specifc Columns](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/82666/88163)

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I was asking. I want to have two custom menus, not hide specific columns in my Google Sheet.

Comment: The referred question have an answer that use multiple menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubén pointed out an [example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82669/88163) using `getUi` method, and here is a different one, using `addMenu` method. "Custom" is the menu name that will appear in the navigation bars, and the names in the list below will appear under it, and call the corresponding functions.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", [
    {name: "Delete and Shift Up",       functionName: "deleteAndShiftUp"}, 
    {name: "Insert New Content Above",  functionName: "insertContentAbove"},
    {name: "Insert Blank Cells Above",  functionName: "insertAbove"},
  ]);
}
```